# Should I use docker exec when running cronjobs with Docker?

Tags: php, docker, cron

I want to run `php-fpm` in one container and `cron` in another container. I have doubts about my method to create the container for `cron`.

At the moment, I just copied the Dockerfile for php-fpm and slightly modified the end of it - installed cron and added `CMD ["cron", "-f"]`

This works, but it's not very DRY, because I've repeated a lot of code when I copied php-fpm's Dockerfile. If some of my dependencies changes (e.g. I need a new php extension to be installed), I have to do it in two Dockerfiles, not just one.

Recently I saw some people use "docker exec from another container" approach to solve this. Meaning that their `cron` container is based on `docker` image and they use `docker exec` to run a command in another container. That's DRY, however, I often hear people saying that running docker-in-docker is for some reason not very elegant and typically for workarounds only.

What would be the best practice here? Leave Dockerfiles in a not-DRY state, or use docker-in-docker approach?

Comment: What do you need the cron job to actually do?  My default suggestion would be to use the host's cron and to `docker run` a new container; this is also what orchestrators like Kubernetes can do for you.

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm running PHP Laravel application and I need cron to periodically call one of framework's built-in commands (`php artisan schedule:run`). So my crontab entry is `* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/artisan schedule:run`

I want every aspect of application to live inside containers, so I want to avoid using host's cron (or anything that lives in the host system).